# Select parameters if a condition is fulfilled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I want to select particular elements if my condition is fulfilled. Please, look below at my code. How can I select the data in CASE clause? My way does not work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
@firstName varchar(100) = '',
@isCounterSelected int,
@countries dbo.tvp_stringArray READONLY
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT [PK_UserID] AS Id
      ,[UserNickName]
      ,[description]
      ,CASE
      WHEN @isCounterSelected = 1 THEN (NULL AS MCount, NULL AS GCount, NULL AS CCount)
      ELSE ''
      END
        FROM [dbo].[User_Existing]      
        WHERE (@firstName NOT LIKE '' AND firstName LIKE @firstName + '%')
        AND Country IN (SELECT inputValue FROM @countries)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry. I've just edited.

Comment: Could you check your CASE statement now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be with syntax errors fixed:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
@firstName varchar(100) = '',
@isCounterSelected int,
@countries dbo.tvp_stringArray READONLY
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT [PK_UserID] AS Id
      ,[UserNickName]
      ,[description]
      ,CASE
      WHEN @isCounterSelected = 1 THEN NULL 
      ELSE ''
      END AS MCount
      ,CASE
      WHEN @isCounterSelected = 1 THEN NULL 
      ELSE ''
      END AS GCount 
      ,CASE
      WHEN @isCounterSelected = 1 THEN NULL AS CCount
      ELSE ''
      END AS CCount
        FROM [dbo].[User_Existing]      
        WHERE (@firstName NOT LIKE '' AND firstName LIKE @firstName + '%')
        AND Country IN (SELECT inputValue FROM @countries)
END
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to have an addidional column when the condition is not fulfilled

Comment: But that's how Sql  works.. . if you are selecting 3 rows then we will have 3 else clauses as well.

Comment: I mean... When the @isCounterSelected = 0 I want to select just PK_UserID, UserNickName and description

Comment: @Matt i think `IF EXISTS` will helpful for you

Comment: Could you, please, give me an example? I have no idea how to do this